# Alert view has no Ok/Close button?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertview

I'm working in the simulator and my app is GPS enabled. So naturally I get a little alert when I run the app that just says I have to have GPS enabled.

But today, randomly(and without a code change to my knowledge) the Close button on the alert just disappeared!

**This is an iOS generated alert/error that fires on app launch.  There is no code associated with it to post.**

[image]

I've reset the simulator, closed/re-opened xCode, changing target iOS versions, restarted the machine, etc.  I can't figure it out!  (And obviously cannot test the app since I'm stuck with this thing open)

Comment: That's the thing...there's not any code.  This is an iOS generated alert/error message that pops as soon as my app loads.

Comment: What is the device your testing on??

Comment: I'm in the simulator.  xCode 4.2, Simulator 5.0

Comment: There is no code!  What do you want? My main.m or something?

Comment: what does your app try to do when starting. please provide the appDidfinishlaunching function of your appdelegate, and any other functions that get called at startup.

Comment: Have you tried reverting to an earlier version of your project and seeing if that fixes things?

Comment: My bad, wow... Why would the underlying framework generate this...

Comment: See my self-answer.  Still clueless as to how/why it happened, but I found a "culprit" I guess.  CodaFi: This message gets popped up when you run apps that use the CoreLocation framework in the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had changed the base URL for my service layer, and it was throwing some sort of silent exception and somehow causing this issue.  The issue went away when I changed the URL back to the working one.

That said, I have NO idea how or why this actually happened.